# Upgrade Gradle from 2.14 to 4.6

Tags: android, gradle

I have problem with upgrade version of gradle. For Gradle 2.14 everything works  correctly without warnings or errors. But when I try to migrate to gradle `4.6` I have problem with my **`ant.importBuild 'build.xml'`** and I've got error:

```
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Declaring custom 'build' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.
```

`build.xml` is correct and work for old version gradle so I have no idea why now problem occurred. What can I do or check to solve this?

Comment: can you provide an extract of your `build.gradle` script ? at least the list of applied plugins?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that your build script is defining a custom `task` named `build`, which is not allowed by Gradle because there is already a task named `build` in the default lifecycle plugin.

There are several issues referenced with this same error message, see:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/make-build-dependson-custom-task/21571
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/declaring-custom-build-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-is-not-allowed/27889

  - https://discuss.gradle.org/t/declaring-custom-build-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-is-not-allowed/27889/4

Do you declare a task `build` in your `build.gradle` ? or maybe you apply a custom plugin that does (see [this answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/declaring-custom-build-task-when-using-the-standard-gradle-lifecycle-plugins-is-not-allowed/27889/4) connected to use of *gogradle* plugin)